# about delete/update record in txt file in C++

Tags: c++

i am writing a c++ program to add, view, modify, and delete records from a ".txt" file.

for example, "trains.txt" file containing fields:
- ID train
- number of seats
- short description
example: (train01, 90, very good train)
and all of the operations must be done direct in the file by using struct or class.
can someone help me ? : )

Comment: Text files will have to be read, and written in sequence, there is no "magical" function to delete or insert text into one. Other than that, you'll have to show what you are doing.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using a standard database format, or DIF, XML etc?

Answer (score 1):

First read all your records to memory. Edit the value on memory. Then truncate your old file and generate a new one based on your memory records. There's no magical way to insert/delete text.

Consider using something like this:

```
struct Train
{
    string id;
    int seats;
    string description;
}

vector<Train> trains;

// read all lines to trains
trains[2].seats = 80;
// write trains to a file
```

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely need to implement your own "database"...
You can avoid rewriting entire file by using fixed length for each field, adding spaces when necessary. Even if some records are deleted, you can rewrite file only from deleted record's position, leaving head intact. Or even mark them as deleted and delete later together.